# Where and how to connect to external API in my service class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, programming-practices

In my service class I would like to connect to external API. Where and how should I do it?

1) Inject in constructor ExternalClass and assign to private property. Next in other property in constructor call connect.

```
public MyClass(ExternalApi externalApi) {
    this.externalApi = externalApi;
    this.ExternalApiConnect externalApiConnect = externalApi.connect;
}    

public void firstMethod() {
   externalApiConnect.first();
}

public void secondMethod() {
   externalApiConnect.second();
}
```

2) Outside constructor, so if I build dependencies in DI, then I don't call connection to external service.

```
private ExternalApiConnect externalApiConnect;

public MyClass(ExternalApi externalApi) {
    this.externalApi = externalApi;

}    

public void firstMethod() {
   if (externalApiConnect == null) {
        externalApiConnect = externalApi.getConnect();
   }
   externalApiConnect.first();
}

public void secondMethod() {
   if (externalApiConnect == null) {
        externalApiConnect = externalApi.getConnect();
   }
   externalApiConnect.second();
}
```

But now I have two repetitions and I have state in my service class. I don't think the state should be in service class?

How is the best way for this?

Edit:

3)

```
public MyClass(ExternalApi externalApi) {
    this.externalApi = externalApi;
}    

public void firstMethod() {
   externalApi.getConnect().first();
}

public void secondMethod() {
   externalApi.getConnect().second();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a smell in your code, you shouldn't ever access a property directly like this `externalApi.connect`
in your ExternalApi class, change the visibility of your instance variable **connect**, from public to private and create a public getter function to access it.

Secondly, if you only need the object connect in your class, you don't have to pass ExternalApi, inject only ExternalApiConnect.

In case you need both, remove the externalApiConnect variable from your class, it is already apart of the externalApi state, why duplicate references to an object...

Comment: Thanks, but what with constructor call and connect with external service in this case? I don't want to connect to external service if I build dependencies.

Comment: @maxu I don't see the relation between building dependencies and connection to an external service, please, could you clarify this point ?

Comment: If I build dependencies, the class's constructor is called.

Comment: @maxu, so you don't have to connect to your api in the constructor, just pass the connection object to your constructor, store it in a variable and use it everywhere or create another function in externalApi  that connects to your api and returns the object, you could also use a pool of connection if your concern is to use just a limited number of connections.

Comment: So my improved second example is good?

Comment: @maxu you could use your second example but the problemis that the variable `ExternalApiConnect ` should not be in MyClass. if you want to use only one connection everywhere,then it is up to ExternalApi to assure it and not MyClass.(for that , you could use singleton pattern natively or with DI Framework)

Comment: I added 3 example. It is the best way?

Comment: @maxu it is way better, what if you pass ExternalApiConnect instead of ExternalApi to MyClass constructor ?

Comment: I would like to avoid connect to API in constructor.

Comment: @maxu ok you wanna do lazy loading, it is better this way.